Why does the following SQL produces different results in MySQL:5.7.44 and MySQL:8.4.0?
I have been hit by the following SQL producing different results in MySQL:8.4.0 and MySQL:5.7.44.
CREATE TABLE subscriptions (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    subscription_id INT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (subscription_id) REFERENCES subscriptions(id)
);
INSERT INTO subscriptions VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO jobs (id,subscription_id,status) VALUES
(1,null,'dispatch_ok'),
(2,1,'dispatch_ok'),
(3,2,'created'),
(4,3,'created'),
(5,null,'created');
SELECT VERSION();
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE
    status = 'created'
    AND
    subscription_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            subscription_id
        FROM
            jobs
        GROUP BY
            subscription_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) >= 1000000000
    )
ORDER BY id

[mysql:5.7.44] [ { 'VERSION()': '5.7.44' } ]
[mysql:5.7.44] []

[mysql:8.4.0 ] [ { 'VERSION()': '8.4.0' } ]
[mysql:8.4.0 ] [
  { id: 3, subscription_id: 2, status: 'created' },
  { id: 4, subscription_id: 3, status: 'created' },
  { id: 5, subscription_id: null, status: 'created' }
]

I expected the following sub query will always produce empty result set, which should evaluates to true for subscription_id NOT IN () even when subscription_id IS NULL. But, that seems not the case in MySQL:5.7.44.
SELECT
    subscription_id
FROM
    jobs
GROUP BY
    subscription_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 1000000000

The fix is - simply add WHERE subscription_id IS NOT NULL into this sub query:
SELECT
    subscription_id
FROM
    jobs
WHERE
    subscription_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    subscription_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 1000000000

But, why? What is going on here?

The same SQL (which creates tables and populates them with data) produces different results in MySQL:5.7.44 and MySQL:8.4.0.

I sadly don't find a reference; the combination of IN, subqueries, NULL, and empty sets have always been a bit inconsistent between the MySQL versions.

Seems like there is some "explanation" (but doesn't make much sense to me) in the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

I'm not sure if I should laugh or cry at this line in the docs: In general, tables containing NULL values and empty tables are “edge cases.” This seems like a dodge - they don't want to explain what happens when there are nulls, so they just call it an edge case (and leave it at that). But for what it's worth, I personally avoid IN or NOT IN for most production code when the list is long or might contain nulls - to me that is just unclear and difficult to reason about, and leaves future maintainers unsure if you knew there might be nulls or not.

@topsail it somehow is “specified” (at least based on how other DBMS handle those cases) as there are couple of bug reports regarding that. But as you said it is not really clear which behavior (based on the documentation) is correct.
